# Where to put file in order to read file ("r") in C

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to read from this file called account.txt however it keeps running the first conditional and printing that it cannot open it. I have pasted the code and included an image[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char code;
    double amount, service, balance;
    double amtCheck, amtDeposit, openBalance, closeBalance;
    int numCheck, numDeposit;
    
    FILE *fpIn;
    fpIn = fopen("account.txt", "r");
    if (!fpIn) {
        printf("account.txt could not be opened for input... \n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("account.txt could be opened for input ;))) \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("checkingAccountLab.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("checkingAccountLab.txt could not be opened for output... \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    amount = 0.0;
    service = 0.0;
    balance = 0.0;
    amtCheck = 0.0;
    amtDeposit = 0.0;
    openBalance = 0.0;
    closeBalance = 0.0;
    numCheck = 0;
    numDeposit = 0;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most systems/platforms look for files (without path prefixes in the given name) in the same folder as the executable (program) file. Try *copying* the file to that folder.

Comment: These will open in the current working directory, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

This code formats you 2 strings, one is the name of your program, the other is the working path of your program. Those strings are useful in combination with FILE operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char directory_separator = '/';
    
    /* this macro needs GNU GCC or G++ as compiler */
    #ifdef _WIN32
    directory_separator = '\\';
    #endif
    
    char *program_name, *working_path;
    if(strrchr(argv[0], directory_separator) == NULL){
        program_name = argv[0];
        working_path = "";
    }
    else{
        program_name = strrchr(argv[0], directory_separator) + 1;
        size_t wp_pn_delimitation = strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(program_name);
        working_path = (char*)calloc(wp_pn_delimitation + 1, sizeof(char));
        strncpy(working_path, argv[0], wp_pn_delimitation);
    }
    
    printf("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("program_name = %s\n", program_name);
    printf("working_path = %s\n", working_path);
}
```